How can I send a GET Request to DirecTV's Sport Domain?
Let me start off by saying, I do not know the best way to title this problem, I apologies if the title is misleading, please feel free to leave suggestions.
I am fairly new to sending POST & GET requests. I worked on an application some time ago that utilized (https://www.directv.com/sports-info/all/all) by pulling the leagues, games, and channels to help sort the data in a format thats easily readable via EXCEL.
Recently, this website was updated (path was changed, and some backend headers were changed), because this occurred, my requests no longer work. I knew the path was the issue so I simply updated all my GET/POST requests via my program to utilize the new path/URL and now I am running into a unknown issue.
The best way to describe the issue is that the program is halting and timing out even with extremely long timeout times, and I am unable to get a response. I can't even get a reliable response using PuppeteerSharp (Basically Chrome Debugging/DevEnv for .NET) Below are things I have tried, and failed. I have no idea what is preventing these requests.
I have tried setting the Origin as the server header access-control-allow-origin exists with "directv.com" and "mvp.directv.com" rather than the previous "*".
I have tried giving the client a UserAgent to pretend to be Chrome.
I have tried inserting specific cookies gathered from my chrome instance of the website (using PuppeteerSharp & manually inserting them) Cookies: XSRF-TOKEN, directv_session, user_id, etc
I have tried setting large timeouts and short timeouts.
I have tried wireshark-ing to confirm it was not being blocked somewhere by my firewall (wouldn't make sense since I can connect to it via chrome, right?)
Manually set ServerCertificationValidation to true to ensure SSL/TLS isn't the issue.
Tried multiple endpoints such as "https://www.directv.com/sports-info/all/all", "https://www.directv.com/sports-info/options/leagues", "https://directv.com/sports-info/all/custom", etc.
Attempted Post Requests to "https://directv.com/sports-info/options/selected" to set location settings etc.
None of this has worked.
Below is what I am currently working with
var handler = new HttpClientHandler
{
    ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback = (message, cert, chain, errors) =>
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Certificate error: {errors}");
        return true; // Only for debugging purposes
    }
};

var client = new HttpClient(handler)
{
    Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(120)
};

client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Origin", "https://www.directv.com");
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.UserAgent.ParseAdd("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/114.0.0.0 Safari/537.36");

HttpResponseMessage res_leagues = await client.GetAsync("https://www.directv.com/sports-info/options/leagues");

See the Postman response below (Stuck on Sending Request)

UPDATE:
After attempting this on multiple networks, it started to successfully get a response. However, after a week or so, (unsure if changes were made on directv's end) it stopped working even on other networks. I am unsure if something was being cached on my client when doing this or not but I am now unable to get a response once again.

Running off postman and export to local, tested this and seems to have worked; might work for you;
var client = new HttpClient();
var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, "https://www.directv.com/sports-info/options/leagues");
var response = await client.SendAsync(request);
response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
Console.WriteLine(await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());


I attempted this and got the same result. I also just used a completely separate network to rule out network interference and found it worked on another network

Ha, that is great! Looks like you may have gotten IP banned or throttled, you may want to reduce the amount of time between calls and use a cors proxy or any proxy for that matter possibly to avoid issues like this. Glad you figured it out! Either local machine rules or remote termination; either way you're on the right track!

Yea, I am running the program from a "Gaming Facility" to help pull sport data in tandem with a bunch of other solutions (Basically exports a excel workbook with the time the sport is on, the sport and the channel from our IPTV service selection). It's a Corporate Network which means I will have to make some calls to see if it can be "allowed" but we will see. Either way, I really appreciate your help.

Try adding these heads, I think it will work
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Referer", "https://www.directv.com");
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept", "application/json, text/plain, */*");
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate, br");
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept-Language", "en-US,en;q=0.9");
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Connection", "keep-alive");


I got the same issue. If you'd like to see the errors I am receiving, I supplied it within a pastebin -> https://pastebin.com/0bDA8zxP

Can you use Postman to see if you can get it?

Running in Postman results the same thing, stuck on "Sending request..." no console logs and nothing happening. I also just used a completely separate network to rule out network interference.

... and found it worked on another network

The issue I was running into was a result of some firewall action on my network end. When switching to an alternate network, these requests fired quickly and correctly without any issue or required headers. Thanks for all the help of the other answers in helping me debug and quickly solve this question/problem.
